# Does $\lim\int f_n=\int f$ imply $\lim\int|f_n|=\int|f|$?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Suppose that $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence complex measurable functions on a measurable space $(X,\Omega,\mu)$.
Let $f$ be the pointwise limit of $f_n$.
Does (1) implies (2)? where
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_Xf_n\,d\mu=\int_Xf\,d\mu.\tag{1}$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_X|f_n|\,d\mu=\int_X|f|\,d\mu.\tag{2}$$

[EDIT] I don't know if the above statement is valid or not.
So please give me a counterexample if it is false.

My trial:
(1) implies
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_X(f_n-f)\,d\mu=0.\tag{3}$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_X|f_n-f|\,d\mu=0.\tag{4}$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_X\Big||f_n|-|f|\Big|\,d\mu=0.\tag{5}$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_X|f_n|-|f|\,d\mu=0.\tag{6}$$
So (2) follows.
I'm not certain whether (3) implies (4).
That is to say that (7) implies (8) where $g_n\to0$ and
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_Xg_n\,d\mu=0.\tag{7}$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_X|g_n|\,d\mu=0.\tag{8}$$
Let $A_n=\{x\in X:|u_n(x)|\ge |v_n(x)|\}$ and $B_n=X\setminus A_n$.
Then
$$\int_X|g_n|\,d\mu
=\int_X\sqrt{(u_n(x))^2+(v_n(x))^2}\,d\mu
\le\int_{A_n}\sqrt2|u_n|\,d\mu+\int_{B_n}\sqrt2|v_n|\,d\mu
\le\sqrt2\int_X|u_n|\,d\mu+\sqrt2\int_X|v_n|\,d\mu$$
So, it is enough to consider "(7) implies (8)" for real $g_n$.

Comment: For positive real valued functions this is the case, but not even for general real valued ones. Consider $X = \mathbb{R}$ and the sequences $f_n := n (1_{[0,1/n]} - 1_{[-1/n,0)}$. Then the sequence converges pointwise to constant $0$ and for every $n$ the integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f_n d \lambda = 0$. However, for each $n$ the integral of the absolute value is $2$.

Comment: Thanks. I think I found another counterexample too. So the statement above is wrong. I see..

Answer (score 4):

False:
Let $X=\mathbb R$ with the lebesgue measure $m$.
Let
$$f_n(x)=\chi_{[-n,n]}\times\frac1{n^2}x.$$
Then $f_n\to0$ uniformly and
$$\int_{\mathbb R}f_n\,dm=0$$
for every $n\in\mathbb N$.
But
$$\int_{\mathbb R}|f_n|\,dm=1$$
for every $n\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: Small mistake: $\int_{\mathbb{R}} |f_n| \, \mathrm{d} m = 1$.

Comment: @Michh I see, Thanks.